# Dropdown items overflow outside container

Tags: html, css, sass, bulma

So I'm having some issues and I don't know how to figure this out and I can't seem to find any guidance at all.

> **Please note**: To render the output, please click on "Run snippet" and then make it full screen as the hamburger icon toggle takes over
> on smaller screens

**The problem**:
When hovering or having active dropdowns in the navigation header, they render outside of the container which at times causes certain items to get cut off.

**Problem example**:
[image]

**What I'm looking to achieve**:
Is it possible to have a dropdown hit the edge of the container on either the left or the right side and then just scoot over to the left or the right? In the image above, you can see the red outline outside the container, but the green outline would push it over and have it render.

**The code**:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  var $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Check if there are any nav burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach(function ($el) {
      $el.addEventListener('click', function () {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        var target = $el.dataset.target;
        var $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        $el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.navbar-item.is-mega {
  position: static;

  .is-mega-menu-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: .375rem 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar ">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="http://bulma.io">
      <img src="http://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" alt="Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox" width="112" height="28">
    </a>

    <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma" target="_blank">
      <span class="icon" style="color: #333;">
        <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
      </span>
    </a>

    <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop" href="https://twitter.com/jgthms" target="_blank">
      <span class="icon" style="color: #55acee;">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </span>
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navMenubd-example">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navMenubd-example" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <a class="navbar-link  is-active" href="/documentation/overview/start/">
          Docs
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-dropdown ">
          <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
            Overview
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
            Modifiers
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
            Columns
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/">
            Layout
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/">
            Form
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/elements/box/">
            Elements
          </a>

          <a class="navbar-item is-active" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/">
            Components
          </a>

          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div>
              <p class="is-size-6-desktop">
                <strong class="has-text-info">0.5.1</strong>
              </p>

              <small>
                <a class="bd-view-all-versions" href="/versions">View all versions</a>
              </small>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-mega">
        <div class="navbar-link flex">
          Blog <span class="tag is-info ml-2">Hover here<span>
        </div>
        <div id="blogDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown " data-style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="container is-fluid">
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">

                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
                  Overview
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
                  Modifiers
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
                  Columns
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>

              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
                  Overview
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
                  Modifiers
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
                  Columns
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/">
                  Layout
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="navbar-content">
              <div class="level is-mobile">
                <div class="level-left">
                  <div class="level-item">
                    <strong>Stay up to date!</strong>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="level-right">
                  <div class="level-item">
                    <a class="button bd-is-rss is-small" href="http://bulma.io/atom.xml">
                      <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span>Subscribe</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <div class="navbar-link">
          More
        </div>
        <div id="moreDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown ">
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/extensions/">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
              <div class="level-left">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <p>
                    <strong>Extensions</strong>
                    <br>
                    <small>Side projects to enhance Bulma</small>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="level-right">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <span class="icon has-text-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-plug"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/expo/">
        <span class="bd-emoji"></span> &nbsp;Expo
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/love/">
        <span class="bd-emoji">❤️</span> &nbsp;Love
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
      <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop-only" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon" style="color: #333;">
          <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop-only" href="https://twitter.com/jgthms" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon" style="color: #55acee;">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <div class="navbar-link">
          More
        </div>
        <div id="moreDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown ">
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/extensions/">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
              <div class="level-left">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <p>
                    <strong>Extensions</strong>
                    <br>
                    <small>Side projects to enhance Bulma</small>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="level-right">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <span class="icon has-text-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-plug"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item is-active has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <div class="navbar-link">
          More
        </div>
        <div id="moreDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown ">
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/extensions/">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
              <div class="level-left">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <p>
                    <strong>Extensions</strong>
                    <br>
                    <small>Side projects to enhance Bulma</small>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="level-right">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <span class="icon has-text-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-plug"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="field is-grouped">
          <p class="control">
            <a class="button is-primary" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/archive/0.5.1.zip">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
              </span>
              <span>Download</span>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section class="hero is-primary">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Bulma.io with Full Width Menu (Mega Menu)
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">
        Hover over Blog
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-4">
          <div class="notification is-light is-link">Hi! <br />I recently launched this project focused on developers. I hope you will find it useful.</div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <figure class="image is-fullwidth">
              <img src="https://codedmails.com/images/banner-codedemails.png" alt="Coded Mails">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p class="title is-4">Codedmails Free</p>
            <p class="subtitle is-6"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/codedmails">@codedmails</a></p>

            <div class="content">

              <p>Ready to use <strong>60+ HTML email templates and themes </strong>for startups and developers for free.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <footer class="card-footer">
            <a href="https://codedmails.com" target="_blank" class="card-footer-item">Visit Codedmails</a>
          </footer>
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the item is absolutely positioned, it's outside of the regular DOM flow. (Not trying to be condescending.) To "keep it" within the container, I would manually move the element over x amount, for example:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .navbar-end .navbar-dropdown:last-child {
      left: -35px;
  }
}
```

Another option, which I know goes against your question, is to position the `.navbar-end` dropdown menus with `right: 0;` instead of `left`.  This will keep the right-side items away from that side though.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .navbar-end .navbar-dropdown {
     left: unset;
     right: 0;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps! (Even a tad )